# Load different content for users from different country

Tags: geo-data

I want to load and show content on my website according to country of the user. How should I go about it.

I wanted to show posts specific to users country. Suppose a user from USA enters my website then I want to show him posts I made only for USA. If someone is from UK then I want to show them posts related to UK only. It should not show posts of USA to UK people.

Comment: What had you tried? What would you consider reliable approach to determine country? Please not that straight asking for plugin recommendations is considered [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: My experience with this is geoip type of tracking. There are databases that you can add for free to your server that you can use to determine where the user is from. I used MaxMind: https://www.maxmind.com/en/home

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use a web service to get the user country using the user's IP. There are a lot of them out there. I will tell you about one of them which is [IP API](http://ip-api.com/) . Here how to use it:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$return = wp_remote_get("http://ip-api.com/json/".$ip);

if ( is_wp_error( $return ) )
            return false;

$data =  json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $return ) );
```

the $data object will be an associative array:

```
    Array(
        [status] => success,
        [country]=> COUNTRY,
        [countryCode]=> COUNTRY CODE,
        [region]=> REGION CODE,
        [regionName]=> [REGION NAME],
        [city]=> CITY,
        [zip]=> ZIP CODE,
        [lat]=> LATITUDE,
        [lon]=> LONGITUDE,
        [timezone]=> TIME ZONE,
        [isp]=> ISP NAME,
        [org]=> ORGANIZATION NAME
)
```

You can fetch the country name or even the city name. and check them with if else statements.